# Auto Emails using SharePoint Designer workflow 2013

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-email

i have created a work flow with below conditions:
1. If Reminder Date is greater than or equal to today
   pause until reminder date
   Send email...
2. If Validation date is equal to today 
   pause until validation date
   Send email...

if have tried to do both conditions within the same step and separate steps. Under both scenarios, an email is sent only for first condition.

My objective is first an email should be sent on Reminder Date (lets say 10th mar) to complete a task. A second email should be sent by validation date (lets say 10 Apr) reminding users that task should be complete by now.

Once i write this workflow and add an task, the first email is triggered but on the validation date the second email is not triggered. the second mail is triggered only if someone manually amends the task (just edit and save also works). i want second email to be triggered once validation date is reached without someone having to manually amend the task every time.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would make 2 seperate Workflows. 1 for the first reminder and start the workflow when a column in SP is on a specific date.

And then make a second workflow for the second reminder with a different column that triggers by date.

The columns should be date columns so you can triger them with the retention feature in SharePoint

How to do this:

Library Settings

> Information Management Policy settings
>
> Document content type
>
> ticked 'Enable Retention'
>
> Select on which column (date column) you want to trigger
>
> Action:  Start the relevant workflow.

Pausing a workflow is not an ideal option because of server recourses.

I Hope this will help you out!
Let me know :)